# Restrict access to files by list of programs

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there any way to restrict access to folder (and files in it) to specific program ?

I am looking to it as a way to be be protected from ransomware. For example, I want to set read/write access to folder with mp3 files only for my media player application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict access to a folder by EXE](https://superuser.com/questions/592216/restrict-access-to-a-folder-by-exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve something like this with different users, but it probably won't be a nice setup and I didn't test it for the details, but a rough schema:

- Create a user (lets call it "musicPlayer") which will be allowed to access your files.
- Assign read (and write) rights for the folders in question to musicPlayer, remove said permissions for your default user
- Start your media player as musicPlayer while beeing logged in as your default user. Use Windows capabilities to do this (Google "Windows 10 run as" or similar, https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html looked good to me)
- Enjoy

Also revoking read access for your default user might be a little bit of an overkill, since it could make it hard to find your files. Even if your media player is allowed to access it, the "open dialog" might be an instance of windows explorer and run with the privileges of your default user.

Basically, you only want your music data to be readable but not writeable. So don't use your administrators account all the time (even if it's hard) but a limited user and remove write permissions for this user on the folder to protect. By this, you can still access your files but in case of an infection, ransomware running as your limited user cannot alter your files and cannot change permissions back to write acces. You still have no issues accessing your data with any program you like. If you have to make changes, use your administrators account and be careful (no E-Mail, no Internet, use a firewall, ...)